# Sci-Fi book about people living on planet traveling on giant water-lily pads

Tags: story-identification

I read a book in the early 80s, probably written in 60s, and all I remember is people travelled on giant floating plant-like life forms, I believe one was nicknamed "Grandpa" or "Grandfather".

Comment: Once again the downvoters making this a welcome place for outsiders

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction and Fantasy SE. Take a look at [this](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) guide to help jog your memory and [edit](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/152274/edit) any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where? Also, take a look at our [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/83527/short-story-about-exobiology-during-human-exploration-of-an-alien-planet

Answer (score 12):

This is a James H. Schmitz story titled "*Grandpa*", where explorers ride a lily pad like creature that starts acting strangely. It is in the anthology ["*The Best Of James H. Schmitz*"](http://www.tor.com/2016/05/03/a-universe-of-possibilities-the-best-of-james-h-schmitz/) from Tor books.